# How to print a warning/error message from my own module?

Tags: printing, message-coding

I would like to print a warning/error message from my own module. Of course I could use `Print["WARNING: my warning"]` but in all the output this would be barely visible. Ideally my user defined message would appear in the same style as those produced by Mathematica built-in functions.

Comment: This is covered well in the documentation here: [Messages](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Messages.html).

Comment: Seems I didn't scroll down to the essential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Mathematica's built-in [message system](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Messages.html); also, I'd suggest looking through Mathematica's package development documentation and tutorials, as these commonly go hand-in-hand; [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PackageDevelopment.html) is one starting place.

As for the specific question, here is an example:

```
MyFunction::argerr = "Bad argument given to MyFunction: `1`";
MyFunction[x_Integer] := Mod[x^2, x+1];
MyFunction[x_] := (
  Message[MyFunction::argerr, x];
  $Failed);

MyFunction[10]
```

> 1

```
MyFunction["abc"]
```

> MyFunction::argerr: Bad argument given to MyFunction: abc
>     $Failed